# Determine Caller Location by Command on PATH

Tags: python, shell, path, python-3.7

If I have a python application installed on my system, is there a way for that application to determine where the call is being executed from?

For example, if the app "myApp" is installed at `Users/myUsr/python/site-packages`, and the app is called from, say, `/foo/bar/`, could the app determine the caller's location on the file system?

In other words:

```
$ # pwd from different location
$ pwd
/foo/bar/

# call "myApp" which is installed at Users/myUsr/python/site-packages
$ myApp -a input.file
```

Maybe this is obvious, but the relative path has to be converted to an absolute path somewhere along the way for this to work.

Comment: It should just be `os.getcwd()` - the directory used when executing the program.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `os.getcwd()` is always the absolute path of the users current directory when the program is run. You may have to do `os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())` but I don't think so (how would abspath work if it didn't already have the abs path of CWD).